# error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm getting this compiler error when calling vector's `size()`. Why?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>


using namespace std;

class Vertex {

    float firstValue;
    float secondValue;
    float thirdValue;

    Vertex (float first, float second, float third){
          firstValue=first;
          secondValue=second;
          thirdValue=third;
    }

};


int main()
{
    cout<<"This program loads a 3D .off object. \nEnter the name of the file that describes it "<<endl;
    string inputFileName;
    getline(cin, inputFileName);

    ifstream inputFileStream;

    inputFileStream.open(inputFileName.data());
    assert (inputFileStream.is_open());

    string actualLine;

    for(;;){

        inputFileStream>>actualLine;

        istringstream actualLineStream(actualLine);



        std::vector<float> results( std::istream_iterator<int>(actualLineStream)
                        , std::istream_iterator<int>() );

       int resultsIndex=0;
       int resultsSize=results.size(); //WHY??

       while (resultsIndex<resultsSize){

         cout<<results[resultsIndex]<<endl;
       }


        if (inputFileStream.eof()) break;

    }


    ofstream outputChannel;

    while (true){} // to keep on console view 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Believe it or not, this line **does not** declare an instance of `std::vector` named `results`, calling the constructor taking a begin and end iterator:

```
std::vector<float> results(std::istream_iterator<int>(actualLineStream),
    std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

This actually **declares a function** called `results` that takes a parameter named `actualLineStream` and another unnamed parameter, both of type `std::istream_iterator<int>`.

Generally in C++, if something looks like a function, it will be parsed like one; the C++ standard requires it. This is really for backward compatibility with C - but this is so counterintuitive that it even has its own name: the ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Some compilers will even issue a warning if it encounters the most vexing parse.

It is related to the fact that these two lines are not equivalent in C++:

```
Foo bar;   // Declares an instance of Foo named bar
Foo bar(); // Declares a function named bar that takes no parameters and returns a Foo
```

To fix it, you can add more parentheses around one of the arguments:

```
//                         +--------- Note extra parentheses!! ---------+
//                         |                                            |
//                         V                                            V
std::vector<float> results((std::istream_iterator<int>(actualLineStream)),
    std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

Or simply declare each iterator separately:

```
std::istream_iterator<int> resultsBegin(actualLineStream);
std::istream_iterator<int> resultsEnd;
std::vector<float> results(resultsBegin, resultsEnd);
```

Comment: Wow.. I would have never thought of that.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this post. This behavior is terrible.

Comment: Yeah, thank God I found this. I was ready to throw my laptop out the window.

Comment: Very nice answer, just a little correction: the two parameters do not have the same type. The first parameter (named `actualLineStream`) is indeed of type `std::istream_iterator<int>`, but the second (unnamed) is of type `std::istream_iterator<int>()`, that is, _"(pointer to) function taking no parameters and returning an `std::istream_iterator<int>`"_. In other words, and since the names of the formal parameters in a function declaration don't matter, the original line is equivalent to `std::vector<float> results(std::istream_iterator<int> param1, std::istream_iterator<int> (*param2)());`.

Comment: Another solution is to use curly brackets: `Foo bar{};` IIRC, this syntax was introduced for constructors for exactly this reason. http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/06/gotw-1-variable-initialization-or-is-it-310/

Answer (score 6):

I think you hit [this bugaboo](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html#faq-10.21). You have managed to declare `results` as a new function that returns a `std::vector<float>`. If I change the line that declares `results` to:

```
std::vector<float> results = std::vector<float>( std::istream_iterator<int>(actualLineStream), std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

I can compile this (with GCC, though, YMMV)