# C++ Constructor / Class Question: Error - left of must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++

I realise what this error means, the thing that is puzzling me is why I get it. I have emulated the error in this tiny program for the sake of this question. Here is the code:

source file:

```
#include "RandomGame.h"

using namespace std;

NumberGame::NumberGame(int i)
{
    upperBound = i;

    numberChosen = 1 + rand() % upperBound;
}

NumberGame::NumberGame()
{
    upperBound = 1000;

    numberChosen = 1 + rand() % upperBound;
}

int NumberGame::guessedNumber(int g)
{
    if (g == numberChosen)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (g < numberChosen)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef NUMBERGAME_H
#define NUMBERGAME_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NumberGame
{
private:
    int upperBound;
    int numberChosen;
    int g;
public:
    NumberGame(int);

    NumberGame();

    int guessedNumber(int);
};

#endif
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "RandomGame.h"
using namespace std;

int makeEven(int);

int main()
{
    //only one of these lines will remain uncommented
    NumberGame newNumberGame(5); // works
    NumberGame newNumberGame;    // works
    NumberGame newNumberGame();  // doesn't work


     // I get the error here, apparently when using empty brackets, newNumberGame 
     //is not a class anymore. wwwhhyyyyy??????
    newNumberGame.guessedNumber(5);

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't done C++ in a while so i'm sure it's something really simple, but why doesn't the empty brackets work? btw it also doesn't work if I just have one constructor with no arguments, or one constructor with a default argument.

Comment: Having `using namespace` in a header **is a bug**. Don’t ever do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
NumberGame newNumberGame();
```

declares a function `newNumberGame()` taking no arguments and returning a `NumberGame`.

C++'s grammar is grown over several decades, rather than being designed in a single act of creation. Consequently, it has many ambiguities that needed to be resolved. This ambiguity was resolved for `a b()` to be a function declaration rather than an object definition.

Comment: so in c++ you always have to instantiate classes that have no arguments without brackets because otherwise it thinks it's a function definition?

Comment: @Sir: I believe this is what my answer is struggling to say.

Comment: no no, your answer was great. Just clarifying. Thanks very much!

Comment: @SirYakalot: In C++11 you can do `NumberGame newNumberGame{};`

Comment: Isn't there a [tag:c++-faq] entry on this? Also, @SirYakalot, for future reference: it's called the "most vexing parse".

Comment: well at least I was vexed by the MOST vexing parse.

Comment: For future explorers, I found this explanation to be very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4175991/3791372