# How to call a object member from different class?

Tags: c++, oop

Hi I am trying to call a object member from different class using inheritance but the compiler seems to complain. Is there an alternative for this?

The error I am getting is error C2228: left of '.func' must have class/struct/union

```
class test
{
public: 
    void func()
    { 
        cout<<"test print"<<endl; // actually performing a complicated algorithm here
    }
};

class demo :public test
{
public: 
    test obj1;
    obj1.func();
};

void main()
{
    demo::obj1.func();// getting an error here
}
```

Comment: _but the compiler seems to complain_. About what?

Comment: error C2228: left of '.func' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Post it in the question

Comment: The code is not valid C++ syntax. StackOverflow is not very suitable as a tutorial site for learning C++.  You cannot write expression statements like `obj1.func()` in the middle of a class declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Constructor / Class Question: Error - left of must have class/struct/union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526538/c-constructor-class-question-error-left-of-must-have-class-struct-union)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

```
// This part is ok (assuming proper header/using)
class test
{
public: 
    void func(){ 
        cout<<"test print"<<endl; // actually performing a complicated algorithm here
    }
};

// You have demo inheriting from test. I don't think you want that
//class demo :public test
class demo
{
public: 
    test obj1;       // Ok
    // obj1.func();  // Not ok. You can't call a function in a class definition
};

void main()
{
    // There are no static functions. You need to create an object
    //demo::obj1.func();// getting an error here

    demo myObject;
    myObject.obj1.func();
}
```

Or, if you want to use inheritance:

```
// This part is ok (assuming proper header/using)
class test
{
public: 
    void func(){ 
        cout<<"test print"<<endl; // actually performing a complicated algorithm here
    }
};

class demo : public test
{
public: 
    //test obj1;     // No need for this since you inherit from test
    // obj1.func();  // Not ok. You can't call a function in a class definition
};

void main()
{
    // There are no static functions. You need to create an object
    //demo::obj1.func();// getting an error here

    demo myObject;
    myObject.func();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, "myObject.obj1.func();" this is what I didn't know

Answer (score 0):

In fact "to call a object member from different class using inheritance", the base function already has that function (it inherits the function)

```
class demo :public test
{
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  demo obj;
  obj.func();
}
```

---

You can also do:

- put `;` at the end of each class.
- `obj1.func()` must be in another function or something...

Try:

```
class demo :public test
{
public: 
test obj1;
demo() {obj1.func();}
};
```

or

```
class demo :public test
{
public: 
test obj1;
void callObj1Func() {obj1.func();}
};
```

and call it like `demo obj;`, respectively `demo obj; obj.callObj1Func();`

of make it static for calling with `::`

Answer (score 0):

you should have a `demo` instance. then call its members.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public: 
    void func()
    { 
        cout<<"test print"<<endl; // actually performing a complicated algorithm here
    }
};

class demo :public test
{
public: 
    test obj1;
};

int main()
{
    demo obj2;
    obj2.obj1.func();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, " obj2.obj1.func(); " This is what I didn't know