# Creating a vector of structures, reserving space, C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Here is my structure declaration:

```
struct  HeapEntry {
    HeapEntry(int a, int b){
        id = a;
        key = b;
    }
    int id;
    int key;
};
```

I'd like to make a vector to store HeapEntry objects, and reserve memory for it since I know how many object I'll need to store.

```
std::vector<HeapEntry> adjList();
adjList.reserve(200);
```

The `adjList.reserve(200)` line produces the error "expression must have class type" though. what going on here?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate, see here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175971/error-c2228-left-of-size-must-have-class-struct-union)

Comment: You've found a very interesting "feature" of C++, the most vexing parse.

Comment: This is not an example of the most vexing parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
std::vector<HeapEntry> adjList;
```

instead of this:

```
std::vector<HeapEntry> adjList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to declare it like this?

```
std::vector<HeapEntry> adjList;
```

Comment: I think I did, whats the difference?

Comment: I believe the trailing parentheses are illegal in C++.  You only use parens if you need to pass arguments to the constructor.

Comment: @Kevin: they are legal, but that's a function declaration.